# In ClojureScript, let a go-loop run until it's channel is exausted

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

A library I'm using, re-frame, uses [a go-loop to process events](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/src/re_frame/router.cljs#L39). In a ClojureScript function I'm writing I need to stop and wait until [that channel](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/src/re_frame/router.cljs#L14) has been exhausted, that is, all events have been processed (including the ones that were generated during the processing of events).

How do I go about it?

A bit of context. I'm writing a library for server side rendering of single page applications and I have mostly in place to run the application in NodeJS, the problem is that I'm doing more or less this:

```
(defn render-application []
  (re-frame/dispatch [:get-data-needed-to-render])
  (reagent/render-to-string [views/main-view]))
```

The event handler `:get-data-needed-to-render` will trigger one or more AJAX requests to the server to get the data needed to render the application, the data needed by `reagent/render-to-string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch `:data-needed-to-render-ready` when `:get-data-needed-to-render` is finished downloading. Then write a handler for it, which will run `(reagent/render-to-string [views/main-view]))`. And in your `main` function, the entry point, just dispatch `:get-data-needed-to-render`.